# Python subprocess redirect

Tags: python, subprocess

I have python subprocess created like this:

```
sub = subprocess.Popen(['./binary'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I want to:

1. Send some input to the subprocess and get some output from it,
2. Redirect the stdin to subprocess stdin and subprocess stdout to stdout,
3. Let the user talk with the subprocess freely, like if the user launched the subprocess himself.

I'm aware that process can be created with it's stdout redirected to the parent stdout for example `ls=subprocess.Popen(['ls'])` will print subprocess' output to stdout. Can it be done to stdin? Can it be done with running process?